# linked server created through windows auth but not with sql auth

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to copy data from ms-access tables on different systems/machine to sql server 2008 on my system. I created a linked server for this to pick table from network drive. For windows authentication it has been created but not for sql auth.

Can anyone help?